# BigQuery channel metrics not matching GA4

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am trying to reproduce channel user counts from GA4 in BigQuery.
I can easily get a total count of users and active users for the day (n=910,000) that is fairly close to what I see in GA4 (n=902,000). However, when I try to break it down by channel the numbers are wildly different.

For example, if I assume direct traffic is:

```
    WHEN 
      collected_traffic_source.manual_medium IS NULL AND 
      collected_traffic_source.manual_source IS NULL AND 
      collected_traffic_source.manual_campaign_name IS NULL AND
      collected_traffic_source.manual_content IS NULL AND
      collected_traffic_source.manual_term IS NULL
    THEN 'Direct'
```

GA4 tells me I had 235k active users but BigQuery tells me it is 610,870!!!

I've compared the `traffic_source` (traffic_source variables indicate the tags of the **first visit** and `collected_traffic_source` variables (collected_traffic_source variables indicate the tags of the **current visit**) for 'first_visit' events assuming they should be equal. I noticed that while `traffic_source` variables captured the tags, sometimes `collected_traffic_source` did not. This is why the numbers I am producing in BigQuery are very different to GA4:

[image]

What I want to know is *why* aren't `collected_traffic_source` variables being populated for first_visit events when it is being captured in `traffic_source`?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the 'traffic_source.source' parameter records the first touchpoint of a user and should be used in conjunction with the 'first_visit' filter to capture the user's initial source of interaction, rather than the 'session_start' filter. However, for session-based sources, use the 'collected_traffic_source.manual_source' parameter with the 'session_start' filter or unnest 'event_params'. Without using the 'event_name' filter, the user may be counted multiple times for each event.

Comment: But for first_visit event shouldn't collected_traffic_source = traffic_source?

Comment: your right, they should be identical